# Change textview of my listview

Tags: java, android, listview, settext

I have been trying for days to find a solution to my problem, but now I've decided to try to ask you. I'm a noob for programming Android, so please forgive me.

I have a main `Activity` with a `Listview` in it.

I am using a `Simplecursoradapter` to feed it with information from my database and a customized layout I made as an XML.

my problem is, I want to change some of the terms or the units that I used in this custom layout, which is not feed through the database.

But if I use settext to the `TextViews` in there it wont run, the app will crash, because my `setContentView` is set to another layout for this class, I guess. I have been looking at `inflaters`, trying to see if I could change the XML programmable, use a string from `String.xml` and change that. But as far as I can see these are not an option. Later I found this code on StackOverflow

```
Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
TextView t = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.txtDisponible);
t.setText("E-ticket validado");
```

But I can't get this to work because the first line isn't working for me. The `Activity` won't give me the `getcontext` method. And even if I did get this to work, I wouldn't know if this would work. Could you guide me in which direction I need to go? As of now, I don't have a class for my `ListView`, is that the way to go. I want to keep this as simple as I can.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT 1:

Okay i tried to put this in my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
    TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kmListview);
    t.setText("bok");
```

The app doesn't crash, but it doesn't change the textview either.

Comment: Setting onyl textView don't solve your problem. You need to keep a list of data in your adapter and you need to update your list. After every updating the list item or items, you need to call notifyDataSetChange() method of your adapter. You have really so much problem with how listView works. I think, it is hardest part of Android. First of all you need to understand ListView, recycle of items in ListView and using ViewHolder (for layouts) in ListView and also managing items (for datas) of listView.

Answer (score 0):

Activity extends ContextWrapper class and you should use this or getBaseContext() because there is no method like getContext() which extends ContextWrapper class.

So use this as Context or getBaseContext() in your Actitiy and I think your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Hmm.. When i put the code in, i get this error

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to com.uniqueapps.driverslogger2.Main

Comment: As far as i can see, this problems occurs because i use the Main activity to do this.. But since i don't have either class or activity for this listview, what should i put in then?

Comment: Follow this link [ https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter ] hope it will help for better understanding.